# MVC data design decision

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am currently in the beginning of designing an MVC application.

While running some tests through a prototype I came across an issue with the way some data is being handled.

Here's a simple [DB diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oM8Z4.png)

When working on my prototype, I noticed that when the Entity Framework builds all of the required models from SQL it creates an ICollection relationship from the Employee_Table to the Job_Position_Link_Table.  I cannot access attributes directly in the Job_Position_Link_Table if the view is strongly typed to the Employee_Table.  Also I cannot get to the Job_Position_Title_Table as well.  I looked into creating a ViewModel for this issue, but cannot find a good tutorial on how to create the ViewModel when you are working with an ICollection.  Most tutorials are from a code first approach, and I am dealing with an inherited database.

The other solution I was thinking of was creating all of my Views in SQL and then passing them into MVC.

I am still new to MVC, and was just wondering what the best practice in this scenario would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never bind your views to EF entities. Instead, create view model classes with required properties and convert the EF entities into these VMs (you can do that manually or with the help of auto mapper). Then, your views can be bound to your view models.

Its the job of controller to build the view model and send it to view engine for rendering. Thus, view must expect a view model ready for presentation.

Comment: What would be the best was to create a ViewModel, where the Entity Framework creates an ICollection<T>?  Right now, when trying to access anything from the ICollection AtElement(int) always throws a null reference exception.

Comment: For join collections, i would write an EF join query and return a custom data contract (IEnumerable<CustomDataType>). Keep the EF entities inside the .Data layer and make your methods returns custom created entities (some call them DTOs others call them Data Contracts)

Comment: Thank you.  I think this will put me on the right track now.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I just figured out what I was doing wrong with my previous ViewModel.  I was treating my ViewModel as a slimmed down version of one of my regular Models.  So instead of selecting all 15 columns from a table my ViewModel was only used to select 5 columns.  It just slipped my mind to include other attributes from other models into a ViewModel then join them together in the controller.